Let $G$ be a group with $A$ abelian and normal in $G$. I want to prove that $G/A$ acts on $A$ by conjugation.
Let $G$ be a group with $A$ abelian and normal in $G$. I want to prove that $G/A$ acts on $A$ by conjugation.
But, my problem is, there are definitely some points where I lack some fundamental understanding. If anyone can help out (be super specific please I am learning!) that would be greatly appreciated. I hope that this post can help others understand a few topics with just this one question.
To start we recognize that $A$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$. We want to show that $G/A$ acts on $A$ by conjugation, so I take that as we just need to show that $G/A \times A \rightarrow A$ by $gA \cdot a = gA a (gA)^{-1}$ defines a legal action?
But my questions come from some misunderstanding.
How do I show that a group acts on another one? (Just by showing that we have defined an action? Like showing identity keeps our object put and an associativity property holds?)
I prove identity holds by showing that $eA\cdot a = eAa(eA)^{-1} = AaA = A$, because A is a group so $AaA=AA=A$.
But did I even show anything? What is the operation on that right hand side?
I am sorry I am so stuck. I greatly appreciate any explanations with group actions. Thank you.

The action is on $A$, not on $G/A$. So the result should be an element of $A$. The action is $gA\cdot a=gag^{-1}$. You need to show this is well defined, and that it is an action.

@Mark Following up on the comment above, to show the purported action is well defined, you need to show that if $gA=hA$ (in $G/A$), then $gag^{-1}=hah^{-1}$.  Putting that in English, you get the same answer for the result of the action no matter which representative you choose from a coset of $A$.

@RobertShore Exactly, and also well defined in the sense that $gag^{-1}$ is indeed an element in $A$. This is easy, but students often forget to explain that.

@RobertShore Okay, thank you! One question: The group that's doing the acting is a set of sets (cosets in this case, as you correctly point out), so that's why we need to check for well definedness. But, do our representatives need to look like $gA$?  So we need to check $gAa(gA)^{-1} = hAa(hA)^{-1}$?

@Mark Thank you for your comment. I'm wondering how we multiply a coset, an element from $A$, and then the inverse of that coset and end up with an element of $A$?

@MCMath This is not multiplication. This is an action of the group $G/A$ on the set $A$. Very formally, what we define is a function $f: (G/A)\times A\to A$ by $f(gA, a)=gag^{-1}$. Just for simplicity we denote $f(gA, a)=gA\cdot a$. But it's not multiplication inside a group.

Correct approach:
In order to let $G/A$ act on $A$ by conjugation, we define a map $\phi: G/A \times A \to A$ by the formula:
$$
\phi(gA, a) = g a g^{-1},
$$
for all $gA \in G/A$ and $a \in A$, which is what "acting by conjugation" means here.
We need to verify that this action is well-defined (the choice of representative from the coset does not affect the outcome). Suppose $gA = hA$ for some $h \in G$. Then there exists an element $a' \in A$ such that $h = ga'$:
$$
\phi(hA, a) = h a h^{-1} = (g a') a (g a')^{-1} = g a' a a'^{-1} g^{-1}.
$$
Since $A$ is abelian, we have $a' a a'^{-1} = a$. Therefore $h a h^{-1} = g a g^{-1}$, and $\phi(gA,a) = \phi(hA,a)$.
Now we need to verify the properties of a group action. We check that the identity element of $G/A$ acts trivially on $A$.
$$
\phi(eA, a) = e a e^{-1} = a.
$$
Also, we verify that the action satisfies the compatibility condition with the group operation in $G/A$. Let $gA, hA \in G/A$ and $a \in A$. We need to check that:
$$
\phi(gA \cdot hA, a) = \phi(gA, \phi(hA, a)).
$$
On the left-hand side, we have $\phi(gA \cdot hA, a) = \phi(ghA, a) = gh a (gh)^{-1} = gh a h^{-1} g^{-1}$ and on the right-hand side, we have $
\phi(gA, \phi(hA, a)) = \phi(gA, h a h^{-1}) = g (h a h^{-1}) g^{-1} = gh a h^{-1} g^{-1}$.
Thus this is a well defined group action.
Why your approach isn't valid:
What you say is not the way to define the map $G/A \times A \to A$. Assume we use the map you give:
$$
\phi(gA, a) = (gA)a(gA)^{-1}
$$
First, $(gA)^{-1} = g^{-1}A$ because it's an element of $G/A$. Also $Aa = A$. Then:
$$
gAa(gA)^{-1} = gAag^{-1}A =  gAg^{-1}A
$$
There is a notion of $AB = \{ ab : \forall a \in A, b \in B \}$. Thus:
$$
gAg^{-1}A = \{ga_1g^{-1}a_2 : \forall a_1, a_2 \in A\}
$$
But $A$ is normal, hence $gAg^{-1} = A$. And $AA = A$.
So we don't get an element of $A$, just all of $A$.

You can save yourself work by defining an action of $G$ on $A$ by $g\cdot a = gag^{-1}$, and then noting that each $x\in A$ acts like the identity so the action factors through $G/A$. Then you don't need to prove well-definedness.
